# LINQ - Select a *TYPED* item in a collection

Tags: vb.net, linq

Can I use LINQ to return an item in a collection that is the same TYPE as the items in the collection? I am a LINQ Noob trying to avoid looping.

```
    Dim mostRecentlyCreatedQuestionnaire As ParentQuestionnaireItem = 

CType((From P In questionnaireCollection Order By P.Metadata.CreateDate Descending).Take(1), ParentQuestionnaireItem)
```

I get an "unable to CAST" error when I include the CTYPE function. I kind of expected that error, but I imagine that if I coul dnot do this, LINQ's usefulness would be diminished and therefore assume that there must be a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that Take(1) doesn't work is that Take(1) returns a `IEnunmerable(Of TSource)` or `IQueryable(Of TSource)` depending on the query, why First return an Object of Type `TSource`

```
Dim mostRecentlyCreatedQuestionnaire As ParentQuestionnaireItem = 
DirectCast((From P In questionnaireCollection Order By P.Metadata.CreateDate Descending).First, ParentQuestionnaireItem)
```

Comment: Other answer voted up, but your answer offers a little more info. Ty

Comment: @Velika, you're welcome, also `DirectCast` is a little better than `CType`

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
Dim mostRecentlyCreatedQuestionnaire As ParentQuestionnaireItem = 

(From P In questionnaireCollection Order By P.Metadata.CreateDate Descending).FirstOrDefault()
```

The problem with your approach is, that `Take` returns an enumerable, even if you just take 1.

My answer assumes that `questionnaireCollection` is strong typed.